# Where are my "/"'s dissapearing to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some a list of links in an unordered list, like so.

```
<div ="HomeRecentBlogs">
   <ul>
     </li>
       <li><a href="item1.html">Item1</a></li>
       <li><a href="item2.html">Item2</a></li>
       <li><a href="item3.html">Item3</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to write a script that will go into each linked page and grab an image and append it to the list item.

```
$('#HomeRecentBlogs ul li').each(function(index, element){
    var link = $(element).find('a').attr('href');
    $.get( link, function( data ) {
       thumb = $(data).find('.PostBody img:first').attr('src');
       $(element).append('<a class="thumb"><img="'+ thumb +'" /></a>');  // This is the problem line
    });
});
```

The problem is that in my resulting code, each list item looks like this:

```
<li>
   <a href="item1.html">Item1</a>
   <a class="thumb"><img="test.jpg></img></a>
</li>
```

I'm pretty sure the line above marked is the one causing the problem

Comment: you're building the string `<img="someurl">` which is invalid. You want `<img src="someurl">`.

Comment: Where does that last part come from?

Comment: To put isherwood's comment in other terms... the HTML you see as output, if viewed in the browser (view source), may be altered from what your program actually outputs.  This is because the browsers automatically attempt to fix poorly formatted HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `<img src="test.jpg"/>` not `<img="test.jpg>`

So you need to change:

```
$(element).append('<a class="thumb"><img="'+ thumb +'" /></a>');
```

to:

```
$(element).append('<a class="thumb"><img src="'+ thumb +'" /></a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a [`src` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-img-src)

```
$(element).append('<a class="thumb"><img="'+ thumb +'" /></a>');
//--------------------------------------^
```

Instead, you're building a string that contains `<img="someurl">`, which is not valid. You want to use `<img src="' + thumb + '" />...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `src` attribute to your images, so use:

```
<img src="'+ thumb +'" />
```

instead of:

```
<img="'+ thumb +'" />
```

inside your `append()` function.